# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi programa este en una sola ventana?

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv, ventana

tengo este código en Python que muestra tres imágenes de la cámara (una normal, otra en gris y la ultima en binario). Junto con una tabla con sliders para colocar valores HSV de un color, haciendo que se resulte el color en la pantalla binaria dejándolo en blanco, y todo lo demás negro. Por ultimo, se puede hacer clic en la imagen normal de la cámara y saldrá una ventana diciendo el valor HSV del pixel.

Ahora, lo que quisiera saber, es si hay alguna forma de colocar todo esto en una sola ventana. Al buscar un poco, pienso que con Tkinter se podría, pero no encuentro forma de que funcione.

Aquí esta el código:

```
#Aqui se estan importando las librerias necesarias
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Esto de aqui, es una funcion para que no de error cuando no se este registrando ningun valor
def nada(x):
    pass

def mouse(evento,x,y,flags,params):
    global e
    if evento == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        e = hsv[x, y]

        valor_hue = e[0]
        valor_sat = e[1]
        valor_val = e[2]

        valor_hue = str(valor_hue)
        valor_sat = str(valor_sat)
        valor_val = str(valor_val)

        Valores = np.zeros((130,300,3), np.uint8)

        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        pos_hue = (10,50)
        pos_val_hue = (10,80)
        pos_sat = (100,50)
        pos_val_sat = (100,80)
        pos_val = (230,50)
        pos_val_val = (230,80)
        fontScale = 2/3
        fontColor = (255,255,255)
        thickness = 1
        lineType = 2

        cv2.putText(Valores,'Hue', pos_hue, font, fontScale, fontColor, thickness, lineType)
        cv2.putText(Valores,valor_hue, pos_val_hue, font, fontScale, fontColor, thickness, lineType)
        cv2.putText(Valores,'Saturation', pos_sat, font, fontScale, fontColor, thickness, lineType)
        cv2.putText(Valores,valor_sat, pos_val_sat, font, fontScale, fontColor, thickness, lineType)
        cv2.putText(Valores,'Value', pos_val, font, fontScale, fontColor, thickness, lineType)
        cv2.putText(Valores,valor_val, pos_val_val, font, fontScale, fontColor, thickness, lineType)

        cv2.imshow("Valores",Valores)




#Aqui se esta creando la tabla para manipular los parametros HSV
cv2.namedWindow('Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')
cv2.createTrackbar('Hue Min','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',0,179,nada) 
cv2.createTrackbar('Hue Max','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',0,179,nada) #Estos son para la Matiz
cv2.createTrackbar('Saturation Min','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',0,255,nada)
cv2.createTrackbar('Saturation Max','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',0,255,nada) #Estos son para la Saturacion
cv2.createTrackbar('Bright Min','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',0,255,nada)
cv2.createTrackbar('Bright Max','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',0,255,nada) #Estos para el Brillo
cv2.createTrackbar('Kernel X','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',1,30,nada)
cv2.createTrackbar('Kernel Y','Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)',1,30,nada) #Y esto es un filtro

#Esta parte es para escoger la camara que se va a usar, siendo 0 la camara predeterminada
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)



while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:

        #Aqui redimensionamos el tamaño de la imagen de la camara para que puedan mostrarse las 3 imagenes
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (350,350))

        #Aqui, pasmos los colores de la camara a formato HSV
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        #Y en esta a gris
        gris = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


        #Es esta parte, estamos leyendo los datos puestos manualmente en la tabla de parametros 
        Tmin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Hue Min', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')
        Tmax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Hue Max', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')
        Pmin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Saturation Min', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')
        Pmax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Saturation Max', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')
        Lmin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Bright Min', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')
        Lmax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Bright Max', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')

        #Aqui se establecen los rangos minimo y maximo en arrays
        color_oscuro = np.array([Tmin, Pmin, Lmin])
        color_brilla = np.array([Tmax, Pmax, Lmax])

        #Por aqui se detectan los pixeles que esten dentro de los rangos y se determina que queda en blanco y el resto en negro
        mascara = cv2.inRange(hsv, color_oscuro, color_brilla)

        #Aqui se leen los datos Kernel de la tabla, los cuales se usaran para hacer el filtro
        kernelx = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Kernel X', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')
        kernely = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Kernel Y', 'Parametros HSV (Matiz-Saturacion-Brillo)')

        #El Kernel se crea para eliminar el ruido
        kernel = np.ones((kernelx, kernely), np.uint8) #Una matriz para crear las dimensiones del filtro
        mascara = cv2.morphologyEx(mascara, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        mascara = cv2.morphologyEx(mascara, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

        
        contornos, _ = cv2.findContours(mascara, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #Encontramos los contornos
        cv2.drawContours(frame, contornos, -1, (0,0,0),2) #Con esto los dibuja

        #Esto es lo que hace que se muestren las 3 imagenes (La normal, la binaria y la gris)
        cv2.imshow("Camara", frame)
        cv2.imshow("Binario", mascara)
        cv2.imshow("Gris", gris)

        cv2.setMouseCallback("Camara", mouse)


        #Y por ultimo, esto es para poder cerrar todo con la tecla Esc.
        k = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if k == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cap.release()
```

Sigo sin saber muy bien como funciona Tkinter o la mayoría de librerías, por lo que si me quieren ayudar, por favor tengan en cuenta eso y explíquenme detalladamente.

Muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: Buen día, y ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Te sale algún error al intentar hacerlo en una sola página?

Comment: Lo primero que intente fue hacer que las 3 imágenes se mostraran en la ventana raíz con Tkinter, pero por alguna razón se quedaba congelado. Lo que tengo actualmente muestra la ventana raíz con seis botones, donde saldrían ventanas emergentes con las distintas imágenes. Lo empecé a hacer así por que no hallaba forma de que funcionara sin que se congelara y pensé que esto seria lo mas parecido. Pero aun así, funciona la imagen normal, pero cuando coloco la gris, se pega.